# Opencv mimics problems in the process of example： SystemError: <class 'cv2.VideoCapture'> returned a result with an error set

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

I am getting this error since Morning. Till yesterday, the script was working perfectly fine. I have unistalled opencv and then reinstalled it . That also dosent fix the problem.

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0,)
while True:
    ret,frame=cap.read()
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('WindowName',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1)&0xFF==ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And the script is working fine in my friend's system.
I reinstalled PyCharm, Opencv, Python and Anaconda, but they didn't work and kept showing this problem.And I can confirm that there is no problem with the environment I configured, the Python version is 3.9.The same problem applies to camera calls instead of directly calling video files

Comment: You suppose to remove comma. Perhaps does this help cv2.VideoCapture(0, c2.CAP_DSHOW) or cv2.VideoCapture(0) If does work then if not: break the do something

Comment: You don't needed to reinstall even if your script is working.

Comment: the `,` makes no difference at all. -- see if you can view the camera image with any other program

Comment: I checked the camera Settings and permission Settings on my computer, and they all worked. When I first ran the program, it worked.